# Grabbing just the content of a line

Tags: python

I have a simple question: I want to just grab the content of a line from a file x. My file x looks like this:

```
PointXY
[387.93852, 200.0]
PointXY
[200.0, 387.93852]
PointXY
[200.0, 387.93852]
PointXY
[200.0, 353.20889]
PointXY
[387.93852, 200.0]
PointXY
[200.0, 387.93852]
PointXY
[200.0, 300.0]
```

My script in Python looks like this:

```
h = open("x.gcode", "r")
searchlines = h.readlines()
file = ""

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "PointXY" in line:
        P = searchlines[i+1]
        print(P)
```

I want P to just be [200.0, 100.0] (for instance). It now gives me '[200.0, 100.0]\n'. How can I adjust this in the line "P = searchlines[i+1]"?

Comment: So you are looking to have it without the '\n'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) the new line character from each line, which you can easily do using the available `strip` method of `str`:

When you get your data in `searchlines`, do:

```
searchlines[i+1].strip()
```

To see that it is actually removed, check the `repr`:

```
 print(repr(P))
```

You can even do that `repr` print before and after applying the `strip()` to see what happened when calling that strip.

Considering the structure of the text you have, you are looking to make it a list, so, you *could* use `loads` from `json` to do this:

```
json.loads(searchlines[i+1].strip())
```

Comment: Thanks, that god rid of the \n, how do I get rid of the ' '? I want P to be [200.0, 100.0], now it stills returns '[200.0, 100.0]'.

Comment: @Henry My answer has been updated to include that already. Check the last line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.strip()` to remove the `\n`

```
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "PointXY" in line:
        P = searchlines[i+1].strip()
        print(P)
```

Comment: Thanks, that god rid of the \n, how do I get rid of the ' '? I want P to be [200.0, 100.0], now it stills returns '[200.0, 100.0]'.

Comment: @Henry You use json.loads. Check my answer.

Comment: @Henry You can use `json.loads` in @idjaw 's answer or us `re` to match the number you want .

Answer (score 0):

if you want delete '\n' use this

after read data

```
data = f.readlines()

data = map(str.strip, data)
```

but isn't necessary for the other you could use this:

```
import ast
listdata = []
with open('lel.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for x in data:
        try:
            if isinstance(ast.literal_eval(x), list):
                listdata.append(eval(x))
        except:
            pass
```

then for get data of list:

```
print listdata
>>>[[387.93852, 200.0], [200.0, 387.93852], [200.0, 387.93852], [200.0, 353.20889], [387.93852, 200.0], [200.0, 387.93852], [200.0, 300.0]]
print listdata[0]
>>>[387.93852, 200.0]
print listdata [0][0]
>>>387.93852
```

Comment: Using `eval` should not be used as a suggested answer, and should not be used in general.

Comment: Sure. Best to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/1832539) . Look up "why is eval bad practice in python". Actually in many languages you will find reasons not to use eval.

Comment: @idjaw Thanks you :3, I've Changed by a small alternative which is ast.literal_eval(). Greetings!

Comment: You're very welcome. `literal_eval` is an appropriate approach. Good stuff.